# How transfer document properties from Office doc to pdf or XML/XPS or set via VB

Tags: javascript, pdf, excel, xps, vba

I am creating Invoices on a PC, and (as well as printing them) want to file them in a folder (for audit reasons).  In the win folder I would like to display the File_name, and Title (containing the customer's name).

If I create them in Excel and (using VBA - set the document property 'Title'), when I file them the document property displays in the folder OK.
But I would prefer to file them as PDF or XML.

I have tried microsoft's XPS document writer and various free PDF print to file programs,
but haven't found one that I can prgramatically set document properties, or where I can transfer document properties from office files (e.g. Excel).

Does anyone know of one that does?
Does it make a difference which version of windows I use?

Other Invoices are created from HTML, so I would like a solution where I could programatically set doc props using Javascript as well.

Comment: Can you not use vba to export straight from excel to xps or pdf? In Excel 2007 I can manually save a spreadsheet as xps or pdf, and the document properties will show properly.

Comment: I don't think Excel 2007 came with a built-in converter like 2010, but a MS one was available as download - so I guess that's what you've got.   My users however have 2003 and I haven't found (yet;-) a converter that transfers properties.  But now that you've told me the 2007 add-in works OK, I'll look to see if it works with 2003.
Thanks for your help.